# Permissions for block devices in FreeBSD

Tags: permissions, bsd

If I look at the permissions of the block devices on a freeBSD box I see the following.

```
crw-r-----  1 root      operator  0x9a Oct 29 17:39 ada0
crw-r-----  1 root      operator  0x9c Oct 29 17:39 ada0p1
crw-r-----  1 root      operator  0x9e Oct 29 17:39 ada0p2
crw-r-----  1 root      operator  0xa0 Oct 29 17:39 ada0p3
```

however, to be able to use usb passthrough on virtualbox, the relvant user needs to be a member of the operator group

so now if I run
dd if=/dev/ada0p1  | od
I am able to get the raw block device, as a non root user, so all file permissions can be bypassed as far as read access is concerned.
Is it safe to and how does one change the default permissions for block devices ? Surely no non root user needs access to sata/sas hard drives (cd drives are different)